# How can I change the location of this piechart on this canvas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Input

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 350)
canvas1.pack()

new_york = float("100") 
paris = float("80") 
london = float("60")
titan = float("40")
brooklyn = float("20")

figure2 = Figure(figsize=(4.2,4), dpi=100) 
subplot2 = figure2.add_subplot(111) 
labels2 = 'New York', 'Paris', 'London', 'Titan', 'Brooklyn'
pieSizes = [float(new_york),float(paris),float(london),float(titan), float(brooklyn)]
explode2 = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  
subplot2.pie(pieSizes, explode=explode2, labels=labels2, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90) 
subplot2.axis('equal')  
pie2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure2, root) 
pie2.get_tk_widget().pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The piechart is being drawn on the center of the bottom row, I would rather it was top row right.
I can't think of anything else to add that's related to that question. 
The only other thing I would like to learn is how to manually assign each pie slices color. 
They seem to be automatic currently.

Comment: Change `canvas1.pack()` to `canvas1.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)` and `pie2.get_tk_widget().pack()` to `pie2.get_tk_widget().pack(anchor=tk.E)`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks, but I'm still confused as to how it works, why would BOTTOM put it at the top row? and which one had anything to do with putting it on the right?

Comment: Oh I see, W for WEST puts it on the left side, very novel.